# Seeking Skincare API: Face Picture Analysis for Acne and Pigmentation

Tags: wordpress, rest

Is there any skincare API available that I can integrate into my client's WordPress website? The API should support functionality like uploading a face picture and returning information on face problems such as acne, pigmentation, etc. If anyone knows of such an API that fulfills my requirements, please share the details. Thank you!

I tried searching on Google for potential APIs, but unfortunately, many of them turned out to be quite costly. I'm still looking for an affordable option that can fulfill my requirements for face picture analysis. If anyone knows of any budget-friendly APIs, I would greatly appreciate your suggestions. Thank you!